# Order data.table by a character vector of column names

Tags: r, sorting, variables, data.table

I'd like to order a `data.table` by a variable holding the name of a column:

I've tried every combination of + eval`,` get`and`c` without success:

I have `colVar = "someColumnName"`

I'd like to apply this to: `DT[order(colVar)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use double brackets for data tables:

```
library(data.table)
dtbl <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 5:1)
colVar = "y"
dtbl_sorted <- dtbl[order(dtbl[[colVar]])]
dtbl_sorted
```

Answer (score 30):

`data.table` has special functions for that matter which will modify your data set by reference instead of copying it to a new object.

You can either use `setkey` or (in versions >= 1.9.4) `setorder` which is capable of ordering in decreasing order too.

Note the difference between `setkey` vs. `setkeyv` and `setorder` vs. `setorderv`. `v` notes that you can pass either a quoted variable name or a variable containing one.

Using @andrewzm data set

```
dtbl
#    x y
# 1: 1 5
# 2: 2 4
# 3: 3 3
# 4: 4 2
# 5: 5 1

setorderv(dtbl, colVar)[] # or `sekeyv(dtbl, colVar)[]` or `setorderv(dtbl, "y")[]`
#    x y
# 1: 5 1
# 2: 4 2
# 3: 3 3
# 4: 2 4
# 5: 1 5
```

Comment: @hibernado Feel free to accept this (more advanced, but ultimately simpler) answer

Comment: @hibernado That's interesting.  Can you please clarify why this doesn't answer your question?

Comment: I specifically want to apply it to DT[order(colVar)]. I find it very frustrating that SO constantly answers questions with new methods. setkeyv is fast but isn't appropriate for my task because I'm using order with another function. I could completely redo it to split the two functions but this would be less clear. Clarity is more important right now than speed.

Comment: I suggested `setorderv` rather than `setkeyv`, but you don't *have* to accept anything, this is your choice. And no, I don't need the points, thank you and have a great day.